# 503 Service unavailable on downloading PDF in Chrome app running from internal network

Tags: google-docs-api

We have a Chrome app, currently published, which downloads a PDF onto the HTML file-system and then displaying in an IFrame. The PDF file is download using the link provided in the content section of the resource feed for a particular PDF resource. Our app was working until yesterday. But, since then, the app receives "503 - Service Unavailable" error when fetching the PDF file. However, we do not get the error when fetching the resource feed for a particular doc. We are using OAuth 2.0 with dual scope, google docs & google user content, to fetch the resource feed and PDF file.

We have found this issue only when running the app in the internal network and not on apps running on other networks. Is this error related to any usage limits?  If so, how can we get this fixed?